# How to add Firebase to Vue.js Tree list

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am attempting to reconfigure a Vue.js Workflowy clone to store list items with Firebase. The clone is based on the following repo: https://github.com/9diov/myflowy. This repo enables the organization of list items into a list tree. List items can be shifted left and right in order to determine their relationship to parent list items. I was successful in implementing an addItem function that adds list items and their levels to Firebase. I am now attempting to implement a method that retrieves items from the database and returns them to the template. So far, I was able to set up a `beforeCreate()` life cycle hook to retrieve the list item values and levels and push them into the list array. I added `console.log(this.list)` to confirm that the data is being added to the array. However, the list values and their levels do not render on the screen. How can I `beforeCreate()` hook to return the `value` and `level` stored in Firebase to the tree list?

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span>{{ msg }}</span>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list"
          v-bind:class="item.level">
        <span>•</span>
        <input
          v-model="item.value"
          @keydown.down.prevent="moveDown"
          @keydown.up.prevent="moveUp"
          @keydown.tab.prevent="shiftRight(index, $event)"
          @keydown.shift.tab.prevent="shiftLeft(index, $event)"
          @keydown.enter.prevent="addItem(index)"
          v-focus="index === focused"
          @focus="focused = index"
          @blur="focused = null">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { fblist } from './firebase'
import { focus } from 'vue-focus';
import Vue from 'vue';

const MAX_LEVEL = 10;

export default {
  name: 'app',
  directives: { focus: focus },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      list: [
        { value: 'new item', level: 0 }
      ],
      focused: null
    }
  },
  async created () {
    let snapshot = await fblist.get()
    const list = []
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let appData = doc.data()
      appData.id = doc.id
      // this.list.push(appData)
      this.list.push({ value: appData.value, level: appData.level })
      console.log(this.list)
    })
    this.list = list
  },
  methods: {
    moveDown: function() {
      this.focused = Math.min(this.focused + 1, this.list.length - 1);
    },
    moveUp: function () {
      this.focused = Math.max(this.focused - 1, 0);
    },
    shiftLeft: function (index, event) {
      let self = this;
      self.list[index].level = Math.max(self.list[index].level - 1, 0);
    },
    shiftRight: function (index, event) {
      if (event.shiftKey)
        return;
      if (index === 0) return;
      this.list[index].level = Math.min(this.list[index].level + 1, this.list[index - 1].level + 1, MAX_LEVEL);
    },
    async addItem (index) {
      this.list.splice(index + 1, 0, {value: '', level: this.list[index].level});
      this.focused = index + 1;
      await fblist.add({
        listItem: this.list
      })
      // this.getData()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

created () hook

```
  async created () {
    let snapshot = await fblist.get()
    const list = []
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let appData = doc.data()
      appData.id = doc.id
      this.list.push({ value: appData.value, level: appData.level })
      console.log(list)
    })
    this.list = list
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeCreate` hook runs at the initialization of your component: **data has not been made reactive**, and events have not been set up yet. Have a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram.

It is quite "standard" to use the `created` hook for fetching a Firestore database (or any other API). In this hook, you will be able to access reactive data.

So just modify

```
  async beforeCreate () {
     //.....
  }
```

to

```
  async created () {
     //.....
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated my component. The created hook appears to retrieve the data values stored in Firebase, according to console.log. However, I am still not sure how to configure this hook to push the ```list.value``` and ```list.level``` stored in Firebase into the ```list``` array and then return those values to the screen in the tree list. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: See the ```created()``` hook example above.

Comment: I want to retrieve the value and level of each tree list item and then push them into the list array

Comment: In the `v-for`, don't do `list[index].level` but just `item.level` and `item.value` instead of `list[index].value`. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vaboxdg8/1/ and also https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: That makes sense. I updated my code above. Still doesn't return the retrieved input to the template. I am also not getting any error messages. console.log confirms that the created hook is retrieving the retrieving the firebase data and pushing it into the list array. So why won't the the values and levels render in the component?

Comment: Have a look at https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-change-input-value-in-vfor/38134

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 Hi did you have time to look at the linked forum posts in the above comment?